# problems creating static library with CoreData - Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

How do I reference the Model that I have created in my static library project?

This returns null and throws and error because the resources live in this static library:

```
     //this code is in the static library
    - (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }

    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"eCommerceEngine" withExtension:@"mom"];
    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return __managedObjectModel;
}
```

How do I change this to pull from this static library?

Comment: When you say the resources live in a bundle, is this a .bundle file because your extension now is .mom ?

Comment: that was a little confusing I guess, updated my question.  The .mom is part of the static library, so i need to create a URL for the .mom in the static library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the iPhone, static libraries have a .a extention and can only contain code. This means that any resources (xibs, images, etc…) must be packed either in a bundle or shipped separately than the library.

See [iOS Library With Resources](http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/iphone-sdktutorials/ios-library-with-resources/)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a preconfigured model from a library, I would suggest building the model programmatically, using the Entity API, and not use a model file at all.

Comment: How does one do this? Documentation link or something helpful? Pretty please :)

Comment: Look up NSEntityDescription.  You can build the whole model in code by creating and linking those descriptions.  It's not that bad, really.